# How to get Magento attribute option id

Tags: magento, layered-navigation, dynamic-url

I am customizing mobile theme for my magento store. I need to implement a search functionality in the front page of my mobile theme. Layered navigation is not there in the default iphone mobile theme. So I had put some piece of code for displaying attributes in a select box and created a search button there. I was successful in publishing the back end attributes there in a select box but can't able to make a search box functionality with that. When observing magento's layered navigation, i found that layered navigation search is working like creating a dynamic URL with selected attribute **value id**. So i decided to create search just like layered navigation does. But for creating dynamic url it seems to be i need a piece of code for fetching the selected attribute option id. I tried many codes for getting that option id, but was not successful. Any one please gave me a hand.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the advanced search functionality instead.
I think that would be much easier. Just a suggestion.

Comment: but i need to publish search fields in home page itself.

Comment: for which attributes do you want to provide a search box functionality

Comment: actually i had put some custom attributes(not custom options) in the back end. I was successful in publishing those attributes in a select box.Actually my plan was to make a search box which is behaving just like select box layered navigation. For that i had observed the layered navigation in magento. They are making a dynamic URL in the value field of each select box options, by getting the **attribute option value id**. So i decided to follow the same concept. But i can't able to fetch attribute option value id, is there any piece of code for fetching this?

Comment: This is the used code :-
 `$attributeCode = 'tyrewidth';

$attributeModel = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);


$select = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
        ->getConnection('default_read')->select()
        ->from($attributeModel->getBackendTable(), 'value')
        ->where('attribute_id=?', $attributeModel->getId())
        ->distinct();

// read used values from the db
$usedAttributeValues = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
        ->getConnection('default_read')
        ->fetchCol($select);`

Comment: `// map used id's to the value labels using the source model
if ($attributeModel->usesSource())
{
    $usedAttributeValues = $attributeModel->getSource()->getOptionText(
        implode(',', $usedAttributeValues)
    );
}`

Comment: For implementing a select box layered navigation, you'd have to populate the select box for an attribute with all possible options that it has. Have you done this?

Comment: yeah that is done, i did populated the select box. but search functionality on select box change is what missing.

Comment: Read this link :

http://www.webdesign-gm.co.uk/news/web-design/magento-web-design/layered-navigation-on-home-page-or-any-cms-page-magento.php

You'll have to integrate your dropdown with it

Comment: Even though that was not the thing i was looking, that link really helped me to change my path, it worked mate, i had created a layered navigation with that. Cheers!!!